# How to Trigger Activity Change After Asynchronous Function

Tags: java, android

I am developing an OCR application and after taking live updates from the Camera and finding the desired text, I start a "Report Activity" to report the findings from the OCR to the user.  It works fine, but I want to have the app take a picture of the camera feed before changing activities.  I included my current Java class where I start the activity in the PictureCallback.  Problem is that sometimes the app changes activities fine while others the app (and debugger) just freeze.  Would appreciate help in understanding why this happens and how to fix it.

**From the OpticalProcessor class (activity is the current activity passed during initialization)**

```
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), ReportActivity.class);
    int flag = 0;

    //Perform OCR Processing

    if (flag > 3) {
        Log.d("Test", "Testing 1234454");
        startAct(intent, activity);
    }
}

private void startAct (final Intent intent, final Activity act) {
    ((OcrCaptureActivity) activity).mCameraSource.takePicture(new com.embocorp.utils.receipt.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSource.ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.d("New", "New");
        }
    }, new com.embocorp.utils.receipt.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data) {
            Log.d("Move", "mobe");
            Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            saveToInternalStorage(bmp, getCurrentTimeStamp(), act, intent);
            act.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String name) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(activity.getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File mypath=new File(directory, name + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
           fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass an Activity? It looks like all you need is a Context

Comment: I'm sorry, what point are you talking about?

Comment: `final Activity act` why do you need this?

Comment: In order to call startactivity

Comment: In other words, it's hard to tell what the full problem is without a [mcve]. What class contains these methods? How is it defined? What is calling these methods and how? Why can't `mCameraSource` be passed to that method directly?

Comment: `startActivity` is a method of `Context`, not `Activity`

Comment: Additionally, you seem to already have `activity` as a variable within `receiveDetections`, and so, I ask: Why does that Activity parameter exist?

Comment: I was under the impression that the variable had to be declared final in order to use in the callback.

Comment: I will edit my question with a minimal example.  Essentially these methods are contained within a OCRProcessing class which is called in the activity class.  Yes the mCameraSource can be passed to the method directly I will try those edits and see if it changes anything

Comment: It needs to be "effectively final", yes. But you appear to have stored that activity as a member variable of the current class, and so there's no need for the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I don't know why anything is freezing. More than likely you are locking up the UI thread somewhere.

As far as the question title goes: async code is handled best if your callbacks are setup correctly.

For example, I see you have a pair of highly coupled classes in which one just has a bunch of callbacks dealing with the Camera.

My recommendation would be to not have an explicit Activity cast in which you are trying to access any fields of that class. e.g. `((OcrCaptureActivity) activity).mCameraSource.takePicture`, and instead if you actually need that class (or rather `mCameraSource`), you should have given that instead. The activity, on the other hand, can implement those callbacks itself, and that is where you should `startActivity` and all those things.

```
import com.embocorp.utils.receipt.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSource;

public class OpticalProcessor {
    // TODO: Implement other interfaces here for receiveDetections method?

    private final Context mContext;
    private CameraSource.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;   
    private CameraSource.PictureCallback pictureCallback;
    private OnDetectionsReceievedListener detectionListener;

    public interface OnDetectionsReceievedListener {
        void onDetectionsReceived(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections);
    }

    public OpticalProcessor(Context c) {
        this(c, null, null);
    }

    public OpticalProcessor(Context c, CameraSource.ShutterCallback shutterCallback, CameraSource.PictureCallback pictureCallback) {
        this.mContext = c;
        setShutterCallback(shutterCallback);
        setPictureCallback(pictureCallback);
    }

    public void takePicture(CameraSource camera) {
        if (this.shutterCallback != null && this.pictureCallback != null) {
            camera.takePicture(this.shutterCallback, this.pictureCallback);
        } else {
            Log.w("OpticalProcessor::takePicture", "Shutter or Picture callbacks have not been set!");
        }
    }    

    public void setShutterCallback(CameraSource.ShutterCallback shutterCallback) {
        this.stutterCallback = shutterCallback;
    }

    public void setPictureCallback(CameraSource.PictureCallback pictureCallback) {
        this.pictureCallback = pictureCallback;
    }

    public void setDetectionListener(CameraSource.PictureCallback pictureCallback) {
        this.detectionListener = detectionCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
        // Maybe this is needed? 
        if (detectionListener != null) {
            detectionListener.onDetectionsReceived(detections);
        }

        // Perform OCR Processing
        int tag = 0;
        if (tag > 3) { // Why would this have worked? It's set at 0...
            Log.d("Test", "Testing 1234454");
        }
    }
}
```

---

And as I said, the Activity implements the callbacks and passes them to the corresponding places.

I assume you were trying to take the picture in response to some click event.

```
import com.embocorp.utils.receipt.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSource;

public class OcrCaptureActivity extends Activity 
    implements CameraSource.ShutterCallback, CameraSource.PictureCallback, 
     OpticalProcessor.OnDetectionsReceievedListener {

    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        // setContentLayout...

        ...

        mCameraSource = ???

        // Pass the context and the listeners here
        final OpticalProcessor processor = new OpticalProcessor(this, this, this);
        processor.setDetectionListener(this); 

        someButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                processor.takePicture(mCameraSource);
            }
        });
    }

    // This method could really be anywhere as long as it has a Context
    public static String saveToInternalStorage(Context ctx, Bitmap bitmapImage, String name) {
        File directory = ctx.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File path=new File(directory, name + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
               fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        Log.d("New", "New");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data) {
        Log.d("Move", "mobe");
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        saveToInternalStorage(this, bmp, getCurrentTimeStamp());

        // Activity started here
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetectionsReceived(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
        // Perform OCR Processing??
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading through your answer several times, I was able to adapt it to a working solution.  The event was not triggered by a button, but the completion of the OCR scan, but I just implemented a custom event listener instead of the onClick listener.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, one more question. The second activity is not being created.  Everything works fine (i.e. the picture is saved to the directory), but the app freezes when it creates the second activity.  I followed the format that you put above to the t

Comment: Then the issue exists within `ReportActivity`, and perhaps you can create a new post containing that code?

Comment: I figured it out.  The Processing event triggered another "takePicture" while the first one was being completed.  I just added a variable to indicate that the camera was being used and locked out subsequent calls until the first one completed.  Thank you it works perfectly now!